# Why does Set-Location say "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '...'"

Tags: powershell

I'm tryin to change my working directory using set-location. This is what I've done so far:

```
Set-Location H:\09- DISTRIBUTION\engineer\drft-tmp\310-DOUGLAS\60kV BLDG Design DWGs
```

Here is the error:

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'DISTRIBUTION\engineer\drft-tm
\60kV'.
At line:1 char:13
+ Set-Location <<<<  \09- DISTRIBUTION\engineer\drft-tmp\310-DOUGLAS\60kV BLDG Design DWGs
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

I'm still a noob. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Hi DATAfiend. I edited your question to clean it up a bit, and give it a better title. However, I get the feeling that you have some spaces (and at least one newline) in there that doesn't belong. Can you check to make sure that what you tried matches what's in the question now, and [edit] further if not?

Comment: @root Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have an app called `TestParam` that takes any number of parameters and echoes them back on newlines:

```
>TestParam thisisatest
thisisatest
```

When there are spaces it considers them a separator between parameters:

```
>TestParam this is a test
this
is
a
test
```

It is the same as typing `Test "This" "is" "a" "test"` and you're essentially passing four different strings. If you want to pass a single parameter that has spaces:

```
>TestParam "This is a test"
This is a test
```

When you look at the error it is saying it can't find a parameter for "DISTRIBUTION\engineer\drft-tm\60kV" which is the second parameter your command is passing to it because you have spaces. If your path has spaces, that's fine, but you need to tell PowerShell that it's all a single parameter and all just one string:

```
Set-Location "H:\09- DISTRIBUTION\engineer\drft-tmp\310-DOUGLAS\60kV BLDG Design DWGs"
```

Comment: "You 'da man!" Many thanks! I never knew about the quotation requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Surround the folder path with double quotes so it reads:

```
Set-Location "H:\09- DISTRIBUTION\engineer\drft-tmp\310-DOUGLAS\60kV BLDG Design DWGs"
```

Comment: Surrounding in quotes = answer.  Removing Spaces = bad idea. :)

Comment: Ok, so NO spaces when you're typing in the path? Who knew?, ok, let me check.

Comment: still struggling...